# Loading information from a text file in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, text-files

I am attempting to save names and scores to a text file with one program and load it from the file in another. The issue is in referencing each name rather than just loading the whole file or just the first name.

It is saved as such:

```
scores = record
        name: string[20];
        Score: integer;

procedure TForm1.BtnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
scoresFile: file of scores;
begin
scoresrecord.name := EdtName.Text;
scoresrecord.Score := Score;
assignfile(scoresFile, 'Teacher.txt');
rewrite(scoresFile);
write(scoresFile, scoresrecord);
closeFile(scoresFile);
end;
```

and loaded into a string grid using:

```
 scores = record
        name: string[20];
        Score: integer;

var 
ScoreRecord: scores;
scoresFile: file of scores;

StrGrdScores.Cells[0,0]:='Name';
StrGrdScores.Cells[1,0]:='Score';
assignfile(scoresFile, 'C:\Computing\AlgebraNew\Teacher.txt');
reset(scoresFile);
while not Eof(scoresFile) do
read(scoresFile, ScoreRecord);
closeFile(scoresFile);
for I := 1 to StrGrdScores.Row do
StrGrdScores.cells[0,i]:=ScoreRecord.name;
```

This is my attempt to load the names, but it just loads the first name in the file into each row. When I work out how to load the names, loading the scores should be obvious. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your first paragraph says the issue is in referencing names, not loading the whole file, but your final paragraph says the issue is in transferring names into a grid. Those are conflicting statements about what the issue is. Please make a better effort to understand what problem it is you're trying to solve. How else will you recognize a solution? Please edit the question to make it clear exactly what it is you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry I'm still doing my A-levels and my knowledge of the industry's terms is very weak. By referencing I meant 'targeting them specifically in order to display them', this may have been the wrong term but others seemed to understand me. Pedantry perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your save procedure appears to only save one record to the file.

Your load procedure reads each row into the same variable, overwriting the previous values. Write the values into the grid as you read them from the file.

```
i = 0;
while not Eof(scoresFile) do
begin
  read(scoresFile, ScoreRecord);
  StrGrdScores.cells[0,i]:=ScoreRecord.name;
  StrGrdScores.cells[1,i]:=ScoreRecord.Score;
  inc(i);
end;
closeFile(scoresFile);
```

You may need to append a row to the stringgrid before writing the value.

Comment: `IntToStr(ScoreRecord.Score)` to write text. `i` should start with 1 as well.

Comment: the load procedure worked perfectly thank you.

you are also correct about the save procedure however when testing it on Friday it saved multiple names and scores, I'm assuming it is the rewrite line but I can't remember what I had there

Comment: Really struggling to save multiple names/scores, which is especially frustrating when I've done it before. It doesn't want to append to a file of records, is there a way around this or do I have to declare it as a textfile and write to it differently (which I tried and it became a nightmare to read on the other side).

Comment: Rewrite creates the file if not there or empties it if it is. You may want to look at [reset](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Reset) instead.

Answer (score 4):

assignfile/write/rewrite/closefile is very old-style Pascal. In Object Pascal and specifically Delphi, there's the TFileStream object to use. But in this specific case, I would suggest the TStringList object. It has LoadFromFile and SaveToFile methods, but also an indexed property Value, which stores values in lines with "Name=Value".

Comment: Thank you that sounds like the fix to my problem. I'll find out about it now and maybe ask if I have more issues.

Comment: although I can see this would have worked, the solution below worked beautifully, by simply reordering my code. thank you anyway